# multiple operations in list of complex objects with lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Let's imagine I have this class:

```
public class Borrow {
   private Float perCent;
   private Float rate;
}
```

and I have a list of `Borrow` objects:

```
List<Borrow> moneyBorrowed = new ArrayList<Borrow>();
```

For each `Borrow` element, I need to multiply `perCent` by `rate` and sum all the results.

I want to use a lambda expression in Java 8. I want to use something like this:

```
    moneyBorrowed.stream().forEach(p -> {
        p.getPerCent() * p.getRate()
    }).sum();
```

but I am not having much luck...

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `forEach`, you need to use one of the `mapXxx` methods. In you case, you can use [`mapToDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToDouble-java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction-) (there is no `mapToFloat` method):

```
double sum = moneyBorrowed.stream().mapToDouble(p -> p.getPerCent() * p.getRate()).sum();
```

Answer (score 6):

`forEach` is a terminal operation that has no returned value, so you can't chain any method call to it.

Use `mapToDouble` to convert your `Stream` to a `DoubleStream`, which you can sum:

```
double sum = moneyBorrowed.stream().mapToDouble(p -> p.getPerCent() * p.getRate()).sum();
```